# EXCEPT keyword in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-except

I'm trying to use the EXCEPT keyword in Oracle 10.1.0.2.0, but kept getting error 'Unknown Command'. I've tried googling around and someone said the keyword is MINUS, so I used MINUS, instead, but I still got the same error. 
Any idea?
Thanks.

So here's my query. 
I'm finding the name of students who enrolls in ALL courses with course number > 500

```
SELECT s.name
FROM Students s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT c.id
    FROM Courses c
    WHERE c.number > 500

    MINUS

    SELECT e.course_id
    FROM Enrollment e
    WHERE e.student_id = s.id
  );
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about the query you're trying to write? Maybe there is another way to construct it?

Comment: @Aiias there are sure other ways to write it, but I'm trying to use EXCEPT/MINUS.

Comment: EXCEPT finally works in Oracle 21c: https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/except-distinct

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Oracle `MINUS` is an operator; it's equivalent to `EXCEPT` in SQL Server.  [Here is a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5557991/1275871) explaining the difference.  Here's a trivial example:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   table_a
MINUS
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   table_b
```

If you still have problems, add the complete query you are using to your question; it's likely a simple syntax error.

Comment: OOh! I figured out what was wrong with my query. There was actual "NOTHING" wrong, except for the fact that sqlplus doesn't seem to like the empty lines I put before and after the MINUS keyword.

Comment: Too funny!  I don't use sqlplus that much myself so this would have stumped me as well.

Comment: Guys, what about duplicates? e.g: 'a', 'b', 'b' MINUS 'a', 'b' Will I have 'b' as result?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 20c will support [`EXCEPT/EXCEPT ALL`](https://twitter.com/RoelH/status/1174455545631141888) keywords.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM t1
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2
FROM t2;
```

or `EXCEPT ALL` if you want to handle duplicates:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM t1
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT col1, col2
FROM t2;
```

> [4.6 Set Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/Set-Operators.html#GUID-5CB549AF-5A4F-453E-B164-49CAC8F94CBF)
>
> Set operators combine the results of two component queries into a single result.
>
> **EXCEPT** All distinct rows selected by the first query but not the second
>
> **EXCEPT ALL** All rows selected by the first query but not the second including duplicates